# Using Igraph library in Julia with PyCall

Tags: python, graph, igraph, julia

I would like to use certain features of the Python library Igraph in Julia-lang. I am aware that there exists a Julia package Graphs but I specifically need Igraph.
I have previously used python libraries with PyCall, but this time when I do.

```
using PyCall
@pyimport igraph
```

But I get error:

```
@pyimport not defined
```

My current Julia version is: 0.4.0-dev+147

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're trying to load a _Python_ module in Julia? I'm pretty sure you can't do that.

Comment: I have used numpy in Julia with using PyCall, and then @pyimport numpy as np ... so I thought it could work...

Comment: The error you posted here says that `@pyimport` is not defined but you've used it successfully before? That's weird. Perhaps `PyCall` didn't load correctly...?

Comment: I used it a couple of months ago and worked... now it does not.

Comment: It doesn't even work using Numpy as you had done before? If that's the case, you might want to file a bug report with the developers on GitHub.

Comment: If it worked a couple of months ago and it no longer does, it probably has something to do with the fact that you're using the dev version of Julia. Does it work if you try it with the most recent stable release? (0.3.7, I think)

Comment: Yes, that just solved it.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Were you able to load igraph as well? If this completely solved the issue, I'll post it as an answer/edit my current answer.

Comment: Yes it does. Please do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the main page of the igraph website:

> igraph can be programmed in R, Python, and C/C++.

So right now there's no official native Julia package for igraph. In general, Julia can't read a package native to another language, so you'll either have to write your own interface for it or find a comparable existing Julia package.

You can browse available Julia packages on http://pkg.julialang.org.

---

Since you edited your question to be specific to PyCall, I'll address that as well.

Note that you're using a development version of Julia. Try using the latest stable release (0.3.7, I believe) and running your code using PyCall again.

Comment: The igraph library looks like it has a pretty clean C API so it would be easy enough to wrap from Julia.